# Problem fitting a regression to time series with trending package

Tags: r, time-series, regression, tsibble, trending

I am trying to fit a negative binomial regression to a time series using the trending package. When I try to calculate the confidence intervals and prediction intervals, I get the error message:

> Error in `cbind()`:
> ! Not supported for tsibble.
> ℹ Please use `dplyr::bind_cols()` instead.

Can someone please help?

Thanks

```
library(surveillance)
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)
library(forecast)
library(trending)

data(campyDE)

countsdf <- campyDE%>%
  select(date, case)

countsdf$date <- as.Date(countsdf$date)

countsdf <- countsdf %>% 
  mutate(epiweek = yearweek(date, week_start = 1))

countsdf <- tsibble(countsdf, index = epiweek) 

countsdf$fourier <- select(countsdf, epiweek, case) %>% 
  fourier(K = 1)

head(countsdf)

model <- glm_nb_model(
  case ~
    epiweek +
    fourier)

fitted_model <- trending::fit(model, countsdf)

observed <- predict(fitted_model, simulate_pi = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are mixing multiple packages that are not designed to work together, and eventually that causes a clash. In particular, the `tsibble` package is designed to work with `fable` for modelling, not with `trending` or with `forecast`.

The only part of the code that relies on `tsibble` here is in the creation of `epiweek` using `yearweek()`, and in obtaining the weekly frequency of the data inside `fourier()`. The only part that relies on `forecast` is in the creation of the Fourier terms.

Here is a modification of your code that avoids the problems by not creating a tsibble object, and computing the two fourier columns directly, rather than via the `forecast::fourier()` function.

```r
library(surveillance)
#> Loading required package: sp
#> Loading required package: xtable
#> This is surveillance 1.20.0. For overview type 'help(surveillance)'.
library(tidyverse)
library(trending)

data(campyDE)

countsdf <- campyDE%>%
  select(date, case) %>% 
  mutate(
    epiweek = tsibble::yearweek(date, week_start = 1),
    fourier1 = sin(2*pi*seq(NROW(campyDE))/52.18),
    fourier2 = cos(2*pi*seq(NROW(campyDE))/52.18)
  )

model <- glm_nb_model(case ~ epiweek + fourier1 + fourier2)

fitted_model <- trending::fit(model, countsdf)

observed <- predict(fitted_model, simulate_pi = FALSE)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>